# Erro: A referência de objeto não foi definida como uma instância de um objeto C#

Tags: c#, .net, nullpointerexception

Queria fazer uma tabela em consola mas toda fez executo o programa surge o erro no método `AlunoLista()`, já tentei fazer alterações mas não consigo chegar lá.

```
     static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var client = new string[7, 7];
            InsertData<ClientHeader>(client);

            Console.Clear();
            InsertData<ClientHeader>(client);
            AlunoLista(client);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        static int getInsertIndex(string[,] matrix)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < matrix.GetLength(0); j++)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(matrix[j, 0])) return j;
            }

            return -1;
        }
        private static void InsertData<T>(string[,] matrix)
        {

            int n = getInsertIndex(matrix), id = 1;

            matrix[n, 0] = Convert.ToString(id++);
            int x = matrix.GetLength(1) - 1;
            matrix[n, x] = "true";

            for (var j = 1; j < matrix.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                do
                {
                    Console.Write($"\nInsert {GetHeader<T>(j)}: ");
                    matrix[n, j] = Console.ReadLine();
                } while (string.IsNullOrEmpty(matrix[n, j]));
            }
        }

        private static string GetHeader<T>(int i) => Enum.GetName(typeof(T), i);


        static void AlunoLista(string[,] lista)
        {
            Console.Clear();
            string linha = new String('-', 49);
            int[] tamanho = new int[] { 4, 10, 10, 20,10,10,10 };


            for (int i = 0; i < lista.GetLength(1); i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(linha);
                Console.Write("|");
                for (int j = 0; j < lista.GetLength(0); j++)
                {
                    if (lista[j, i] != null) lista[j, i] = "";
                    string espaço =new string (' ', tamanho[j] - lista[j, i].Length);

                    Console.Write($"{lista[j, i]}{espaço}");
                    Console.Write("|");
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            Console.WriteLine(linha);
        }


        enum ClientHeader { Id, Name, Surname, Addres, CodPostal, Telephone, Email, State };


    }
}
```

Comment: Onde dá o erro? Você precisa dar o máximo de informação possível para podermos ajudar.

Comment: desculpe não ter sido claro o erro dá na variavel: string espaço =new string (' ', tamanho[j] - lista[j, i].Length); no Método AlunoLista

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 1):

Na linha anterior ao erro está transformando em *string* vazia se o que encontrar **não** for nula, o que não faz sentido. Faz todo sentido fazer essa transformação se for nula. Mudando isto resolve o problema. Melhorei algumas coisas, mas acho que dá para melhorar mais. Tem coisa que realmente não é ideal, mas pode ser requisito.

```
using static System.Console;

public class Program {
     public static void Main(string[] args) {
         var client = new string[7, 7];
         InsertData<ClientHeader>(client);
         InsertData<ClientHeader>(client);
         AlunoLista(client);
     }
    static int getInsertIndex(string[,] matrix) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix.GetLength(0); j++) if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(matrix[j, 0])) return j;
        return -1;
    }
    private static void InsertData<T>(string[,] matrix) {
        int n = getInsertIndex(matrix), id = 1;
        matrix[n, 0] = (id++).ToString();
        int x = matrix.GetLength(1) - 1;
        matrix[n, x] = "true";
        for (var j = 1; j < matrix.GetLength(1); j++) {
            do {
                Write($"\nInsert {GetHeader<T>(j)}: ");
                matrix[n, j] = ReadLine();
            } while (string.IsNullOrEmpty(matrix[n, j]));
        }
    }
    
    private static string GetHeader<T>(int i) => System.Enum.GetName(typeof(T), i);
    
    static void AlunoLista(string[,] lista) {
        var linha = new string('-', 49);
        int[] tamanho = new int[] { 4, 10, 10, 20, 10, 10, 10 };
        for (int i = 0; i < lista.GetLength(1); i++) {
            WriteLine($"{linha}|");
            for (int j = 0; j < lista.GetLength(0); j++) {
                lista[j, i] = lista[j, i] ?? "";  // <===================== mudei aqui
                var espaço = new string (' ', tamanho[j] - lista[j, i].Length);
                Write($"{lista[j, i]}{espaço}|");
            }
            WriteLine();
        }
        WriteLine(linha);
    }
    enum ClientHeader { Id, Name, Surname, Addres, CodPostal, Telephone, Email, State };
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/ht2d55). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/9orHPT). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Array/Intanciation.cs).

Comment: eu acho que ainda algum erro de lógica nesse código porque agora quando executo aparece "count" não pode ser negativo. acho que é da subtração (' ', tamanho[j] - lista[j, i].Length);

Comment: Deve haver, mas aí é outro problema. Se não conseguir resolver abra outra pergunta passando o máximo de informação possível para que seja fácil as pessoas te ajudarem.